# Referral exclusions and Organic Search from Management API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference (management api) to get some of the website statistics, filters and other stuff. But I can't find any way to download website refferal exclusions list or list organic search for that account. Is there any way to do it or it's just impossible to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is not possible. There aren't API, in this moment, ti get Referral Exclusion list.

Comment: Ohh, after extensive study of API reference I was afraid that this would be the answer, but anyway thanks for the reply :)